# C# regex: match a string starting with x and ending with y, not including the ending part & match the last occurence of a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I've got a sql statement like this and we need to modify it for our own use:

```
SELECT distinct  [testCountry].[Division] as c0
FROM (....) AS testCountry 
WHERE ([testCountry].[Division] <> '' and [testCountry].[Division] is not null)
ORDER BY [testCountry].[Division] asc
```

The (....) part contains other sql statements, may include keywords `SELECT, WHERE, ORDER BY` as well. 
Here I'd like to delete the Where clause at the end "`WHERE ([testCountry].[Division] <> '' and [testCountry].[Division] is not null)`"

How do I compose the regex for this?

I've tried sth like this:

```
string res = Regex.Replace(originalSql, @"(WHERE[\S\s]*?)(ORDER BY)", "$2");
```

but it would delete all the `WHERE` in other places followed by `ORDER BY`. 
Also how to write the regex more succinctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Why use `[\S\s]` instead of just dot `.`?

Comment: The original sql statement has line breaks, like what you would see in sql server management studio

Comment: You know there are setting that let you tell it if dot should or should not match newlines.

Comment: Oh, could you find a link for it? I'd like to use that

Comment: If you insert ` OR 1=1 ` before the last `ORDER BY` it will have the same effect. Or you could reverse the string and delete everything between "YB REDRO" and the first occurrence, and including, of "EREHW".

Comment: See [this](https://regex101.com/r/kDesQw/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your help, but I don't think it will work in our case, we have multiple such sql statements, table and column may not necessarily be testCountry and Division

Comment: Replace the hard-coded names with `\w+`.

Comment: @strisunshine It's [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you match the other `WHERE`s, then you don't have to worry about replacing them. Try

```
string res = Regex.Replace(originalSql, @"(.*)(WHERE[\S\s]*?)(ORDER BY)", "$1$3");
```

By nature of a greedy match, this will ensure that only the last `WHERE` clause is matched.

For the record, I like [Joshua's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43332002/211627) better. Avoid regex when you can and whoever comes after you (including your future self) will be grateful.

Comment: Thanks! I changed .* to [\S\s]* again, but I think it accomplishes what I'd like to do in a concise way :)

Comment: Does this work? Have you tested it because it seems to be greedy to me?

Comment: If you use [singleline mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) then you can still use `.`.

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury I tested it kept my other WHERE clauses, in case in future there is other problem I'll consider using lastIndexOf, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't a regex solution like you requested, but it's a solution.

```
var sql = "WHERE THIS = THIS WHERE this = that ";

var index = sql.LastIndexOf("WHERE");

var sqlnew = sql.Substring(0, index);
```

You could use the above to remove last WHERE statement. Then it is much easier to append your on where statements on the end.

if you can also get the last WHERE statement and regex out what you need much easier.

```
   var whereStatement = sql.Substring(index, sql.length);
```

Then get what you want example you gave..

```
string res = Regex.Replace(whereStatement , @"(WHERE[\S\s]*?)(ORDER BY)", "$2");
```

Comment: Thanks. that's useful, though I need to keep whatever there is after that where clause

Comment: but you all ready know how to do that? I've amended my post, you can get  last where statement and regex what you need etc

Comment: @strisunshine I'd recommend you use `sql.Substring(0, sql.LastIndexOf("WHERE")) + sql.Substring(sql.LastIndexOf("ORDER BY"));` Much easier to read and maintain than regex (in my opinion).